# How can I conditionally format a specific row of a table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a way that I can do conditional formatting for a specific row in a Power BI table?  I have percentages that I need to highlight in green, yellow, and red based on how close the current forecast % is to the OSD goal %. I have tried to format the numbers, but it does it for the whole column and all I need is my middle value (highlighted in the picture) to be conditionally formatted.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[image: Funding Block]